# Sequelize: Remove a field from model data before validating

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a situation where I'm working with PII obfuscation. When fetching info from the service, for example, a SSN value would be obfuscated as `'*********'`. Now I need to handle a situation where a frontend might update other info and send that obfuscated SSN right back to me. In that case, I want to be sure I don't save the obfuscated version.

I have some working code, but I don't typically like relying on `modelInstance.dataValues` so I'm wondering if there's a different/better/more idiomatic way to get this done:

```
Member.beforeValidate((member, options) => {
  const ssnRegex = /[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{2}-?[0-9]{4}/gi;

  // Before we validate model info, we want to remove any
  // obfuscated values.
  if (member.ssn && !ssnRegex.test(member.ssn)) {
    delete member.dataValues.ssn;
  }
});
```

I did try to `delete member.ssn`, but that didn't fly and I don't see a `modelInstance.remove()` (or similar) method in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

As you suspect, there's no `instance.remove` method or equivalent, and I agree manipulating the model instances feels off. The way Sequelize handles this situation is to pass in an array of `fields` during update. This tells Sequelize only to update the fields passed in the array:

```
const fields = ['name'];

if (!ssnIsObfuscated()) {
  fields.push('ssn');
}

memberInstance
  .update(req.body, {fields})
  .then(() => {
    // do something
  });
```

As a precaution, you could also add a `validate` method on the `ssn` field. This will only fire if `ssn` is included in the create or update:

```
ssn: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING,
  validate: {
    isObfuscated(value) {
      if (ssnIsObfuscated()) {
        throw new Error('No good');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to validate since this should be transparent to service consumers. I was just hoping for a "tighter" way of interacting with model properties before save. Maybe this is the best I'm going to do.